# Visual Studio - Execute Project in Python Interactive - Not working

Tags: visual-studio, python-interactive

In Visual Studio I'm trying to execute my script in the Interactive Window (Ctrl+Shift+F5), however I get either one of the following error messages (depending on whether I executed commands in the Interactive Window yet):

```
The interactive window has not yet started.
```

Or

```
Resetting Python state.
The interactive Python process has exited.
```

Is this expected? How can I make it work?
I'm using Windows 7, Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.2.5..

Thanks

[image]